# How to go to definition of method or procedure in Delphi 7?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

How to go to definition of method or procedure in Delphi 7? If ctrl key + mouse-click, it goes to the method declaration. I want it to go to the actual method instead, similar to "go to definition" in Visual Studio.

**Update:**

I want to jump to where proc2's code is defined.

```
procedure proc1

begin 
  proc2
end
```

Comment: Ctrl + Shift + ↑ (or ↓)

Comment: See my update. This causes the cursor to jump to proc1's line. I need to jump to proc2's code.

Comment: As TLama said - Ctrl+Shift+DownArrow will bring you from the interface section (proc1) to the implementation section (proc2).

Comment: @gabr The update is showing the implementation code for proc1. I have the cursor on 'proc2'  which is the call to proc2. If I hit ctrl +shift + ↑ (or ↓) on it, the cursor jumps to the declaration of proc1 in the interface. That's not what I want. I want to jump to the implementation of proc2.

Comment: Also what's the equivalent context menu option for this?

Comment: In Delphi XE, ctrl + mouse click or "Find Declaration" goes to the implementation. Delphi 7 behaves differently.

Comment: At least you can Ctrl+click and then type Ctrl+Shift+↑

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's a two-step process:

1. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+click the identifier you want to navigate to. That will take you to the declaration (as you've already observed).
2. Once the cursor is on the declaration, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>↓</kbd> to navigate to the corresponding definition.

   You can press that key combination again to go back to the declaration. (The up and down arrow keys are equivalent in this keyboard shortcut; it doesn't actually matter whether you want to navigate up or down within the file.)

Comment: Alt + ↑ key combination will also take you to the declaration of a method or variable (on a good day)